# How to upload videos from the frontend using "featured video plus plugin " in WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

How can I upload videos from the frontend using "featured video plus plugin" in WordPress? I am using customize theme and wrote this function for upload, but it doesn't work

```
function upload_video(id,fvp_nonce,fvp_video) {
    $.post( ajaxurl, {
    'action'    : 'fvp_save',
    'id'        : id,
    'fvp_nonce' : fvp_nonce,
    'fvp_set_featimg':'false',
    'fvp_video' : 'http://localhost/1213044.mp4',
    'fvp_sec'   : "correct"
    });
}
```

Comment: Click the small media icon in the Featured Video input box on the post edit screen and upload your video or choose it from the media library. WordPress does not support all formats

Comment: Yes you are right this option works in backend (wp-admin ). My question is I want to create or use same functionality in WordPress front end ?